# Importing jar files to project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) to add a JAR file in my project. The JAR file was correctly added to my Referenced libraries, but when I try to use the classes defined there (using an import statement), I get an error telling me that the import cannot be resolved. I checked the jar file and it contains all the classes I am trying to import. What might be the problem?

The jar file is lingpipe-4.1.0.jar 
The import statement is

> import com.aliasi.chunk.CharLmHmmChunker;

Comment: Did you already try restarting eclipse?

Comment: yes I did restart eclipse

Comment: Can you add your import-statement to your question?

Comment: yes it is in the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import-statement looks fine, so it has to be an eclipse-specific problem.

Clean your project by going to `Project -> Clean`.